# MANOVA or Mixed Models

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, manova, multivariate-regression

We are doing an interesting behavioral study on waterbirds. Let me explain the design of the study before asking the statistical advice.

The lake is divided into 2 parts, In one part fishing is allowed **(FA)** and in the other **(NFA)**, it is not. We selected one vantage point in FA and one in NFA. Our observations were on three species of waterbirds **WB1, WB2, WB3**.
Behavior is divided into five classes (**Be1,Be2,Be3,Be4,Be5**)
**Be1= Alert behavior, Be2= Locomotion, Be3= Feeding, Be4= Courtship, Be5= Resting**

So the observer observed the waterbirds from a vantage point in FA or NFA and recorded the number of waterbirds out of the whole flock engaged in the above-mentioned behaviors every 5 minutes from dawn to dusk for one day/months in FA and one day in NFA, for one whole year. We have divided **daylight hours into 4-time intervals**: dawn (D) (sunrise-0800), morning (M) (0800-1200), afternoon (A)(1200-1600), and evening (E) (1600-sunset).

**Objectives:**
Now we want to see the effect of  **(1) FA and NFA. (2) diel time period (dawn, morning, afternoon and evening) in FA and NFA, and (3) boat traffic, on the behavior of WB1, WB2, and WB3**.

Note:
The dependent variables are the percent of flock engaged in behaviors (Be1: Be5), and as one behavior can affect other, so we cannot say that they are independent of each other.

So do you think using MANOVA is a right approach? Some people suggested us using Multivariate Generalized Linear Mixed Models with site as a Random effect, but with only two sites will it work?
Can someone suggest what should be the structure of such model? 
I will be thankful if someone could suggest a solution in R.

This is how our data sheet looks for each month (This is for specie WB1):

```
Be1<-c(0.012,0,0,0.028,0,0,0.011,0)    
Be2<-c(0.038,0,0.032,0.0289,0.007,0,0,0.016)    
Be3<-c(0.513,0.556,0.613,0.522,0.486,0.710,0.744,0.545)    
Be4<-c(0.449,0.247,0.133,0.339,0.295,0.278,0.210,0.362)   
Be5<-c(0.141,0.167,0.145,0.058,0.058,0.043,0.111,0.099)   
Boats<-(5,4,1,10,3,1,0,3)  #number of boats during that obs time
Area<-(FA,FA,FA,FA,NFA,NFA,NFA,NFA)    
Time<-(D,M,A,E,D,M,A,E)    
Month<-(Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan,Jan)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks for providing the context. That always helps!

My own approach to this would be neither of the choices you suggest.  Rather, I'd change the dependent variable. Without a lot more knowledge of bird behavior and a lot of time spent looking at the data and talking with you, I can't say exactly how I would change the DV and I might have to try several things, but the idea would be to change the 5 percentages into a single variable. Cluster analysis might work. Or you might have strong intuitions about how this could be done.  Certainly a bunch of graphs could help.

Once that is done, the problem becomes much simpler.

Comment: Could you use linear discriminant analysis (related to MANOVA) to find linear combination of behaviors that maximally separates vantage points and proceed from there? It seems a waste to use unsupervised cluster analysis when you have class labels to use a supervised method.

Comment: @Eumenedies You'd still have to code the behaviors somehow.

Comment: @PeterFlom, Thanks for your answer. The problem with changing the DV is that some behaviors are opposite to each other. I am sorry I should have explained the behaviors also. Be1= Alert behavior, Be2= Locomotion, Be3= Feeding, Be4= Courtship, Be5= Resting
So you can see that according to our hypothesis, Birds in the Fishing area (FA) should show more locomotion or alert behavior due to the number of boats. So I guess combining them all is not practical, Am I right?

Comment: The fact that some are opposite makes it, if anything, more important to turn them into one (or maybe two) variables that are interpretable.